# What will happen to the migration notice after betas are removed?

Tags: support, migration, migrated-questions, post-notices

After questions have been migrated from the [closing beta sites](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/), will the notice of migration still be shown on the destination site after the parent site has been removed or will the migration history disappear?

[image]

Comment: "**migrated** from The Twilight Zone 11 hours ago"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with the answer to most questions, it appears that only time will tell. And the old girl came through once again this time.

**The migration notice is still displayed on the destination site just as it always was, even after the original parent site has been shut down for good.**

[image: migrated from economics.stackexchange.com]

A live example of this is visible on the Philosophy site: 
[Why can't (or shouldn't) economists answer normative questions?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2683/why-cant-or-shouldnt-economists-answer-normative-questions)

Now, the next question is, should moderators on the new destination site clear the migration history for those questions which have found a happy, new, permanent home?